# Edittext how to move chars to the left if filled

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an edittext which has a width depending on another view on its top which is a textview. I set both the views to wrap content so that the edittext will copy the textview's width. But, when the edittext is completely filled up, the characters make a new line. How can I make it such that when the edittext is completely filled up the characters are only moving to the left. If possible, I do not want to hardcode the width. Is there any solution for this? Thanks.

Comment: can u give your xml layout of edittext

Comment: android:singleLine="true" only

Comment: @migs your welcome and don't forget to vote me up dude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your EditText XML:

```
android:singleLine="true"
android:maxLines="1"
```

Comment: Note that `android:singleLine` currently works, but it is [deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#singleLine) and won't work in the future

Answer (score 1):

`android:singleLine="true"` only